# How to open  file to edit tw.pol in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors

How to open to in unknown encoding to edit (tw.pol) in Ubuntu?

Comment: @none111, If any of the answers here helped, could you mark them as accepted? If they didn't, maybe some insight on how we can better help you would aid in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails, use the terminal.

**Try asking for some info on the file**

```
$ file tw.pol
```

**Open it in vi (emacs if you must)**

```
$ vim tw.pol
```

A quick google search tells me that .pol is a file extension used by Microsoft to manage registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot open a file with gedit, try the Gnome Hexadecimal Editor, which can be installed at the command line with:

sudo apt-get install ghex2

or search for hex editor in the ubuntu software center.